# Is there an easy way to swap the sign of a formatted number?

Tags: c#, number-formatting

I fully accept that this may not be possible, but it seems worth a question to see if anyone has a simple answer.

I have a field that has a user-defined format of Cn or Fn. The user wants to be able to also, optionally, swap the sign on the value (so -123.4 would be displayed as £123.40, for example). Is there a simple means of doing this using standard formats? Nothing I can find indicates this is possible, and I would have to generate some form of user-defined string to represent these instead (which would be possible, but problematic for all sorts of reasons).

The reason is for accounting purposes, where the figures are stored the opposite way round from how they are most easily interpreted. We cannot change the raw data, and changing hte data before format is also not straightforward.

Comment: You want to swap from positive to negative and vice-versa or always positive? What means _formatted number_?

Comment: Both negative to positive and positive to negative. All I mean is that the number is being displayed using a format definition.

Comment: Why can't you use `decimal swappedVal = -1*val;` ? What means formatted number?

Comment: Because I want to do this using a format, if at all possible. It is a grid display and the user needs to be able to change this on the fly. I don't have easy access to the raw data.

Comment: I still don't understand how the user can change it and why you can't do that.

Comment: The user clicks on a column (sort of) and says Swap Sign. At that point, I don't have access to the data, because it is already formatted in the grid. U can however say that this column needs to have this format.

Comment: _It is a grid display_ If you don't tell us what the actually involved controls are how could we help?

Answer (score 0):

> The user clicks on a column (sort of) and says Swap Sign. At that
>   point, I don't have access to the data, because it is already
>   formatted in the grid

Can't you use this approach?

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var cell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
    if(cell.Value == null) return;

    // say this is for example: £123.40
    var ukCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
    decimal value;
    if (decimal.TryParse(cell.Value.ToString(), NumberStyles.Any, ukCulture, out value))
    {
        cell.Value = (-1*value).ToString("C", ukCulture);
    }
}
```

Everytime the user clicks on this cell the value's sign will swap.